# How to use to use Pentaho Kettle when we have 2 distinct arguments

Tags: json, csv, pentaho, kettle

I am new to kettle and I am kind of stuck in this. I want to read a JSON file and a CSV files, and then change values in the CSV file according to some in JSON before storing it. For example if I have in a CSV row a value saying "test", and in the JSON something like {"key": "test", "value": "val"}, I want to replace the "test" in the CSV with "val" before storing in the DB.

However I am not sure how I can do that, I think the thing I must use is the "User Defined Java Class" step but I have no idea how to access to each argument individually inside it, since I can only seem to be able to read CSV rows one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that modifying an existing CSV file would not be the best practice in your case.

Rather, I would suggest that you consider using Kettle to actually transform the data and generate a CSV file that fits the bill as your desired result.

In the most generalized way possible, kindly look at the following process (see screenshot below):

1. Retrieve data from a JSON input, retreive data from a CSV file input;
2. Do some magic/clean up/staging of the data columns;
3. Join the two streams on specific values;
4. Write a new CSV file or overwrite the existing one;

[image: General example]

I hope this helps a bit.